# using different serializers Django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

hope someone can help me out.

I am trying to call different serializes depending on some factors, and one of the factor is if the field called "code" (which is inside MyCards table) is not null then call the rewardsSerializer.

the point is that I am not managing to get to get the value of code to see if it's None or not.

down here you can see how I have tried to get the value of "code" with no success

'''
class MyCardsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = MyCardsSerializer
queryset = MyCards.objects.all()

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.GET.get('code') != None:
        return RewardSerializer
    if self.action == 'update':
        return UpdateMyCardsSerializer
    else:
        return MyCardsSerializer
```

'''

Comment: Your `MyCards` table is refering to a django model and has a attribute named `code` based on what you said but in this script you return different serializers based on the `code` query parameter of the request, it does not execute any logic based on models field.

Comment: How are you passing the attribute `code`?
inside body or as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MyCardsViewSet(ModelViewSet): 
        queryset = MyCards.objects.all()
```

if you are passing the `code` as parameter, then only you can get the value using
`self.request.GET.get('code')`

if you are passing the `code` inside body, you have to access it using
 `self.request.data.get('code')`

then you can rewrite the code as

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.data.get('code') != None:
        return RewardSerializer
    if self.action == 'update':
        return UpdateMyCardsSerializer
    return MyCardsSerializer
```